# how to sort items in the list

Tags: android, listview

i have a list which contain names of an item correspondingly its quantity,
if i add the same item in the list it should add the quantity only..,
can u please give me any idea 
thanks in advance

Comment: the title and the question have nothing in common?!

Comment: @user624290 if I understand correctly you have a list that contains items that look like `name, quantity` in some form, and you want to do something like `List.Add(name, quantity)` and if `name` is already present in the list, then just add the existing and new quantities together?

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<K key, V Value>();

//fill the data

if (map.containsKey(key)
{
    V value = map.get(key);
    value += new_value
    map.remove(key);
    map.put(key, value);
}
else
{
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

You could also use a Dictionary. There are several different solutions.